How can I use Rusoto with WebAssembly
I am trying to set up an rust serverless function using the rusoto crates but am unable to build without the following error "run pkg_config fail: pkg-config has not been configured to support cross-compilation."
Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "audio-generation"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[patch.crates-io]
tokio = { git = "https://github.com/second-state/wasi_tokio.git", branch = "v1.36.x" }
socket2 = { git = "https://github.com/second-state/socket2.git", branch = "v0.5.x" }
hyper = { git = "https://github.com/second-state/wasi_hyper.git", branch = "v0.14.x" }

[dependencies]
hyper = { version = "0.14", features = ["full"]}
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["rt", "macros", "net", "time", "io-util"]}
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"

hound = "3.5.0"
rusoto_core = "0.47.0"
rusoto_s3 = "0.47.0"

Dockerfile:
FROM docker.io/library/rust:1.80.0-slim-bookworm as builder
RUN apt-get update && apt-get clean
RUN rustup target add wasm32-wasi
ENV RUSTFLAGS="--cfg wasmedge --cfg tokio_unstable"
RUN mkdir /build
COPY . /build/
RUN ls -lah /build
WORKDIR /build
RUN cargo build --target wasm32-wasi --release
RUN ls -lah
RUN chmod +x target/wasm32-wasi/release/hello-world.wasm

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /build/target/wasm32-wasi/release/hello-world.wasm /
ENTRYPOINT ["/hello-world.wasm"]

Error:
Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.103
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.103`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/build/target/release/build/openssl-sys-9877a50e972148ea/build-script-main` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(osslconf, values("OPENSSL_NO_OCB", "OPENSSL_NO_SM4", "OPENSSL_NO_SEED", "OPENSSL_NO_CHACHA", "OPENSSL_NO_CAST", "OPENSSL_NO_IDEA", "OPENSSL_NO_CAMELLIA", "OPENSSL_NO_RC4", "OPENSSL_NO_BF", "OPENSSL_NO_PSK", "OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED_3_0", "OPENSSL_NO_SCRYPT", "OPENSSL_NO_SM3", "OPENSSL_NO_RMD160", "OPENSSL_NO_EC2M", "OPENSSL_NO_OCSP", "OPENSSL_NO_CMS", "OPENSSL_NO_COMP", "OPENSSL_NO_SOCK", "OPENSSL_NO_STDIO"))
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(openssl)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(boringssl)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl250)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl251)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl252)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl261)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl270)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl271)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl273)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl280)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl281)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl291)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl310)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl321)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl332)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl340)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl350)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl360)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl361)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl370)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl380)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl381)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl382)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl390)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(libressl400)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl101)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl102)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl102f)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl102h)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl110)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl110f)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl110g)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl110h)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl111)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl111b)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl111c)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl111d)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl300)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl310)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl320)
  cargo:rustc-check-cfg=cfg(ossl330)
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=WASM32_WASI_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  WASM32_WASI_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=WASM32_WASI_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  WASM32_WASI_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=WASM32_WASI_OPENSSL_DIR
  WASM32_WASI_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_wasm32-wasi
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_wasm32_wasi
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_wasm32-wasi
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_wasm32_wasi
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_wasm32-wasi
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_wasm32_wasi
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  run pkg_config fail: pkg-config has not been configured to support cross-compilation.

  Install a sysroot for the target platform and configure it via
  PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR and PKG_CONFIG_PATH, or install a
  cross-compiling wrapper for pkg-config and set it via
  PKG_CONFIG environment variable.

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-sys-0.9.103/build/find_normal.rs:190:5:


  Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys` crate cannot
  proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed and this crate had
  trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable for the
  compilation process.

  Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
  For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.

  If you're in a situation where you think the directory *should* be found
  automatically, please open a bug at https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl
  and include information about your system as well as this message.

  $HOST = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  $TARGET = wasm32-wasi
  openssl-sys = 0.9.103


  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
Error: building at STEP "RUN cargo build --target wasm32-wasi --release": while running runtime: exit status 101

I already tried updating the Dockerfile to include pkg-config and set the PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR environment variable but was not succesful..
